# Python: PYQT5 submit button and outputting to text file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

[FormScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjxqs.png)

I am very new to python, and I have created a form that requests information from a user, and Im currently stuck (and clueless on where to start) on creating a functional submit button for the form.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is when the user enters his output directory and hit submits, it prints to a text file. So for example if he browses through and hits C:/Users/Folder
and hits submit, it will output to a text file saying Output_Dir = "C:/Users/Folder"

I am guessing after I create my submit button, I will have to create a function that it calls that writes to the text file.

#### UI CODE

```
self.browse_1 = QPushButton(self.input_files1)
    self.browse_1.setObjectName(u"browse_1")
    self.browse_1.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 75, 23))
```

#### main code

```
 ##Output Directory Button:
    self.ui.browse_1.clicked.connect(self.browsebutton_Function)

 ## SUBMIT FIELDS  INPUT FILES
    
    self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.textFileOutput)

  ##Output Directory Function:
def browsebutton_Function(self):
    file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
    if file:
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(str(file)) 


def textFileOutput(self):
    output_DIR = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
   
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        print(f" Output Directory = {output_DIR}", file=text_file)
```

Comment: Yah, so what I want to do is write to a text file when I hit the submit button.

Comment: Writing a file with python is pretty basic, and you can get thousands of results just by typing "python write text file" in the StackOverflow search box (and ***million*** results by googling it). In your code there is absolutely no attempt in writing a file, did you actually try something before posting? If your attempts weren't successful, then [edit] your post and show us those attempts.

Comment: I just edited it to what I have, my apologies for that. My question is , how do i get the text thats entered into the lineEdit field to appear in the text file as well. This is where im stuck.

Comment: Sorry about my first comment, I was distracted and I wrote something wrong: `getExistingDirectory()` does *not* return a tuple, only functions that open file selections do that. That said, since you're already writing the value in the line edit, the solution is quite simple: `text_file.write("Output_DIR = {}".format(self.ui.lineEdit.text())`. Note that: 1. the return value of `getExistingDirectory()` is already a string, so there's no point in using `str()`; 2. you should first check that `self.ui.lineEdit.text()` is not empty (possibly by also using `strip()`).